# Retrieving Sim Serial Number on Android 13

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sim-card, android-13

In Flutter, I want to get the serial number of the sim. I used the package [sim_data_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sim_data_plus). It works perfectly fine for Android 12 and lesser versions. But even though the package says that it provides support for Android 12 and above, I am not able to read the serial number of a sim present in a phone running on Android 13. I do not intend to get the mobile number, I intend to get the sim serial number.

Comment: That is [an OS restriction](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids).

Comment: it is not possible even android 12 devices also

Comment: It is possible in Flutter. I am able to get the serial number of a sim in android 11 and android 12.

Comment: Hi @Kirthana, Can you check once again and confirm it whether that library works in android 11 and 12 ?

Comment: Because in the official document itself they have mentioned like that only

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get sim serial number android 10 or higher

- If your app doesn't have the permission and you try asking for
  information about non-resettable identifiers anyway, the platform's
  response varies based on target SDK version:
- If your app targets Android 10 or higher, a SecurityException occurs.
  If your app targets Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, the method
  returns null or placeholder data if the app has the READ_PHONE_STATE
  permission. Otherwise, a SecurityException occurs.

According to android's official [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getSimSerialNumber())

[image]